# How to prevent mvn jetty:run from executing test phase?

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

We use MySQL in production, and Derby for unit tests. Our pom.xml copies Derby version of persistence.xml before tests, and replaces it with the MySQL version in prepare-package phase:

```
 <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <executions>
   <execution>
    <id>copy-test-persistence</id>
    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
     <tasks>
      <!--replace the "proper" persistence.xml with the "test" version-->
      <copy
       file="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml.test"
       tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"
       overwrite="true" verbose="true" failonerror="true" />
     </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
     <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
   </execution>
   <execution>
    <id>restore-persistence</id>
    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    <configuration>
     <tasks>
      <!--restore the "proper" persistence.xml-->
      <copy
       file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml.production"
       tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"
       overwrite="true" verbose="true" failonerror="true" />
     </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
     <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
   </execution>
  </executions>
 </plugin>
```

The problem is, that if I execute mvn jetty:run it will execute the test persistence.xml file copy task before starting jetty. I want it to be run using the deployment version. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jetty:run` goal *invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase `test-compile` prior to executing itself*. So skipping tests **execution** won't change anything.

What you need to do is to bind the `copy-test-persistence` execution to a lifecycle phase posterior to `test-compile` but prior to `test`. And there aren't dozen of candidates but only one: `process-test-classes`.

That's conceptually maybe not ideal, but it's the least worse option, and  it will work:

```
 <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <executions>
   <execution>
    <id>copy-test-persistence</id>
    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
    <configuration>
     <tasks>
      <!--replace the "proper" persistence.xml with the "test" version-->
      <copy
       file="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml.test"
       tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"
       overwrite="true" verbose="true" failonerror="true" />
     </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
     <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
   </execution>
   ...
  </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the arguments [-Dmaven.test.skip=true or -DskipTests=true in the command line](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#skip-test). For example

```
mvn -DskipTests=true jetty:run ...
```

Not sure if this skips the process-test-resources phase, though.

More info about skipping tests [is available in the Surefire plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html).

Comment: If forgot to mention that I tested that already, but it does not help.